# Scrapy spider which listens on a queue for seed urls to crawl?

Tags: scrapy

What is a way I could go about having a Scrapy spider listen on an SQS queue (or other) for new seed URLs to crawl?

Couldn't find any examples in the documentation so thought someone may know on here.

Thanks in advance.

edit:

Is this `start_requests` right place perhaps?

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        # read requests from queue here?
        while True:
            url = self._queue.get_url()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

Comment: Yes, `Spider.start_requests()` is the way to go here. Reference documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reimplemeting [`Spider.start_requests()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) is the right way to dynamically yield requests for your spider to process, wherever those requests come from (a dynamic queue, a local file, etc.).

The [Scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) covers this, by the way :)